# what is it called when a song is created by overlaying a series of repeating beats

Tags: electronic-music

This used to be pretty popular on YouTube but i have seen much of it in a few years. Wikipedia doesn't seem to categorize it as either a type of electronic music or a style of DJing.

Comment: An example would significantly improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few music techniques here:

Looping is done by using a tape or two (or more) that plays back what was previously recorded.  An example is here: [Cam Neufeld - Beaufort Sea Boogie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeiBEBEC_Jo)

Beat-hopping is a technique done by techno artists where several rhythms are played on turn-tables and they use mixing techniques (cross-fader, filter slider) to bounce between the records and loops they are playing in efforts to create new rhythms.  An example is [Ritchie Hawtin - Minus Orange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zlpB6V-yYs).  Here the main rhythm is taken from [Yello - Oh Yeah.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jJkdRaa04g)